# Adding the same comment to every code file in a Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, comments

Background: We are using VS 2008 and are in the process of upgrading from TFS 2005 to 2008.

We have a solution that contains several projects and overall have hundreds of code files.  We want to add the same text as a comment to all of these files (a copyright message).  Does anyone know of a quick/easy/efficient way to do this?  Also, is there a way to do this via TFS so we don't have check out and check in every file?

I found some code on CodeProject on creating a macro which does this, but you have to open each file individually and then run the macro on each one, which we were hoping to avoid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be trivial for you guys to write a simple program which iterates through all of the directories, and all of the code files (assuming *.cs or the like) and add text to the top.

It should take less than 20 minutes to build, test, and run that.

As far as TFS is concerned, just perform a checkout command from the top of the tree.  It will check out every file in source control.  When done, you can check in from the top as well.

Assuming C#, look at System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories()...

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.org) installed, you can use the following Bash script:

```
# Process all .cpp and .h files under the directory tree at $PROJECTROOT
# To add other file types, add more "-o -name \*.ext" clauses.
# $COPYRIGHTFILE is the file containing your copyright message
COPYRIGHTLENGTH=$(wc -l $COPYRIGHTFILE)
for file in $(find $PROJECTROOT -name \*.cpp -o -name \*.h); do
    if diff <(head -n $COPYRIGHTLENGTH $file) $COPYRIGHTFILE; then
        (cat $COPYRIGHTFILE; cat $file) > /tmp/file
        mv /tmp/file $file
    fi
done
```

This finds every .cpp or .h file under the directory tree $PROJECTROOT, compares the beginning to the copyright message, and if it differs, prepends the copyright to the file via a temporary file.

DISCLAIMER: Untested, test first and use at your own risk.

Comment: I had to tweak slightly : if ! diff -q <(head -n $COPYRIGHTLENGTH $file) $COPYRIGHTFILE &>/dev/null; then

Answer (score 1):

I have [published code](http://rexcardan.com/codesnippets/adding-a-copyright-to-visual-studio-project) that does exactly what you are trying to accomplish in 20 lines.

A reference of that code is included below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = "C:\\...TopLevelFolder";
    string copyright = "//Copyright © 2011 Rex Cardan, Ph.D";
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        if (file.Split('\\')[file.Split('\\').Length-1]!= "AssemblyInfo.cs")
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(file))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("\r\n");
                sw.WriteLine(copyright);
                //Normalize Line Endings
                sw.WriteLine("\r\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is encouraged to include the complete solution (i.e. code) in the answer, beside the link.

Answer (score 0):

> [I]s there a way to do this via TFS so we don't have check out and check in every file?

It's a good idea to have this change be part of the files' change histories.  So, you **do** want to check out & check in all files.

Kevin Pilch-Bisson's blog post "[Formatting all C# files in a solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/kevinpilchbisson/archive/2004/05/17/133371.aspx)" is a good resource.  You can modify that algorithm to make the edits.